# Save std::set in std::list

Tags: c++, list, set

I have a set:

```
std::set<Proc*> finalProc = getFinalProc();
```

I just want to copy all elements from this set into a list. I thought I have to iterate through the set and save the elements in the list? I guess I made a major mistake but I can't find a solution for this:

```
std::list<Proc*> firstLevel;
for(std::set<Processor*>::iterator it = endProcessors.begin(); it != endProcessors.end(); ++it){
    firstLevel.push_back( ???? );
}
```

The idea was to `push_back` all iterated elements?

Comment: You have already been shown the better way to do this, but just for completeness, you would replace `????` with `*it`. `it` is treated somewhat like a pointer, so `*` "dereferences" it, and gets the value, which would then be pushed into the `list`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a much better way to do that:

```
std::list<Proc*> firstLevel(finalProc.begin(), finalProc.end());
```

In your original code you should have replaced `????` with `*it` and `endProcessors` with `finalProc`

As @luk32 notes, possibly you have a bug (if you want to copy the actual data, not the pointers). In this case you can see @luk32 solution or I would go for `std::unique_ptr` here (smart pointers is a preferred way to manage memory in modern C++):

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Proc>> firstLevel;
for(const auto& ptr: finalProc){
    firstLevel.push_back(std::make_unique<Proc>(*ptr));
}
```

All memory pointed by pointers in firstLevel will be automatically freed after going out of `firstLevel` visibility scope.

Comment: so damn simple... thanks. what the wrong idea with the push_back from the iterator?

Comment: I see a bug incoming. Note that he stored pointers to `Proc`. You will make copies of those references. Not sure if this is intended.

Comment: I'm saying that if OP by saying "save the element" mean saving its state, this will not work as expected. I know this copies contents of list. I am asking if this is the real intent.

Comment: @user Ok, this is important to know. I saw codes that stored pointers on list but wanted to copy actual objects. I also saw codes that wanted to copy references. I just felt it needed a clarification.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of using smart pointers. I had the similar code, and trust me, freeing the elements twice when copying pointers around is way easier, and happens more often than it seems. I would stress it out even more.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I know, after comments that this answer does not help OP, however it was not clear at first. Thus I would like to leave it, if anyone ever came here and wanted a way to copy actual objects. Just for the sake of completeness.

If you want to make copies of the pointers to `Proc` objects go for sashas answer.

However, if you want to make copies of the actual objects that are held in set you need to explicitly copy them.

```
std::list<Proc*> firstLevel;
for(std::set<Processor*>::iterator it = endProcessors.begin(); it != endProcessors.end(); ++it){
    firstLevel.push_back( new Proc(**it) ); //1
}
```

**[1]** Dereference iterator, dereference pointer to get the actual object, then make a new `Proc` object from it, and push the pointer from new onto list.

I see already downvotes, so maybe I will try to elaborate.

If you copy only references - pointers. Then modification of things in list will be reflected on the items of set, and vice-versa as they store `Proc*`. If the intention is to copy actual `Proc` objects. The posted code does it.

Edit:
To reflect comment.

Of course it is important to remember that when you store the pointers, when the container gets destroyed only its element get d'tors called. In this case that would be `Proc*`. I means that only pointers would be lost. If we make explicit copies of the elements when creating a vector, of course we need to explicitly iterate and use `delete` on each element to properly free the memory. An alternative would be to use smart pointers, but the original example did not, so I left it as well.

Comment: thanks. pointer copies are just fine. but i will keep this in mind. thanks

Comment: @sasha Haha, ok I understand completely, but a comment like this would be fine. However, the same problem persist, in your answer, its even more dangerous i think, be cause the elements need to be deleted only once. One needs to care where to do it. Especially if you have multiple copies of pointer to the same element.

Comment: @luk32, in my case everything is fine, as I make a copy. And `unique_ptr` automatically deletes it later.

Comment: @sasha I see you edited your answer. Now its really nice I up-voted it. I leave mine only if some in the future came to this question and wanted to make copy of the actual elements.

Comment: @luk32, feel free to leave it as you made it earlier than me. And +1 for your attention)